# How to insert a line after a match using sed (or awk) in a formatted JSON file?

Tags: macos, awk, sed

```
{
  "id": "a1234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef",
  "properties": {
    ...
    "my_id": "c1234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef",
    ...
}
```

Given the above in a file, I want to be able to perform a match (including the 4 leading spaces) on `my_id` and then append a new line     `"my_value": "abcd",`.  The desired output would look like this:

```
{
  "id": "a1234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef",
  "properties": {
    ...
    "my_id": "c1234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef",
    "my_value": "abcd",
    ...
}
```

Using examples online, I'm unable to get the command to work.  Here is an example of something I have tried: `sed '/.*"my_id".*/a "my_value": "abcd",' test.json`, for which I receive the following error: `command a expects \ followed by text`.

What is the correct way to structure this command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`awk` procedure with passed argument for insert value**

The following `awk` procedure allows for `'abcd'` to be passed as an argument for insertion (allowing it to be set in a bash script if required).

```
awk -v insertVal="abcd" '/"my_id":/{$0=$0"\n    \"my_value\": \""insertVal"\","} {print}' dat.txt
```

**explanation**

The required insertion string (`'abcd'` in this case) is passed as an argument using the `-v` variable switch followed by a variable name and value: `insertVal="abcd"`.

The first `awk` `action` block has a `pattern` condition to only act on lines containing the target-line string (in this case `"my_id":`). When a line with that `pattern` is found, the line is extended with a new line mark `\n`, the required four spaces to start the next line, the specified `key` named `"my_value"`, and the value associated with the key, passed by argument as the variable named `insertVal` (`"abcd"`), and the final `,` character. Note the need to escape the `"` quotes to render them.

The final `awk` block, prints the current line (whether or not it was modified).

**test**

The procedure was tested on Mac Terminal using GNU Awk 5.2.0.

The output generated (from the input data saved to a file named `dat.txt`) is:

```
{
  "id": "a1234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef",
  "properties": {
    ...
    "my_id": "c1234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef",
    "my_value": "abcd",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -v new='"my_value": "abcd",' '{print} sub(/"my_id":.*/,""){print $0 new}' file
{
  "id": "a1234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef",
  "properties": {
    ...
    "my_id": "c1234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef",
    "my_value": "abcd",
    ...
}
```

The above will print the new line using whatever indent the existing `"my_id"` line has, it doesn't assume/hard-code any indent, e.g. 4 blanks.

I'm using this:

```
sub(/"my_id":.*/,""){print $0 new}
```

instead of the briefer:

```
sub(/"my_id":.*/,new)
```

so it won't break if the new string contains any backreference chars such as `&`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -e '/my_id/{p;s/id.*"/value": "abcd"/' -e '}' input_file
{
  "id": "a1234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef",
  "properties": {
    ...
    "my_id": "c1234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef",
    "my_value": "abcd",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following GNU `awk` code. Where `newVal` is an `awk` variable having new value in it. Using `match` function in GNU `awk` where I have used regex `(.*)("my_id": "[^"]*",)(.*)` which creates 3 capturing groups and saves values into an array named arr. Then printing values as per requirement.

```bash
awk -v newVal='"my_value": "abcd",' -v RS=   '
match($0,/(.*)("my_id": "[^"]*",)(.*)/,arr){
  print arr[1] arr[2] newVal arr[3]
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/"my-id".*/p;s//"my-value": "abcd"/' file
```

Match on `"my-id"` and print that line, then substitute the additional line.